# URL encoding Content-Disposition attachment

Tags: cross-browser, http-headers, filenames, urlencode, content-disposition

Should the file name in `Content-Disposition` be URL encoded?

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my file with spaces.png
```

or

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my%20file%20with%20spaces.png
```

I've tried with mixed results.

I have a library I'm using and it gets URL-encoding-happy. I don't know if it's correct in doing that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)

Answer (score 0):

No. URL-encoding is a hack for obsolete browsers that do not support the standard way of doing things, defined in http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html